# Unable to create sample data for avro schema Error creating a kafka message to producer - Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

Tags: json, google-cloud-dataflow, avro

Unable to Error creating a kafka message to producer - Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

```json
    {
    "namespace": "de.morris.audit",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "AuditDataChangemorris",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "employeeID",  "type": "string"},
        {"name": "employeeNumber", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
        {"name": "serialNumbers", "type": [ "null", {"type": "array", "items": "string"}]},
        {"name": "correlationId",  "type": "string"},
        {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"},
        {"name": "employmentscreening","type":{"type": "enum", "name": "employmentscreening", "symbols": ["NO","YES"]}},
        {"name": "vouchercodes","type": ["null",
            {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "name": "Vouchercodes",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                        {"name": "voucherName","type": ["null","string"], "default": null},
                        {"name": "authocode","type": ["null","string"], "default": null}
                    ]
                }
            }], "default": null}
    ]
}
```

when i was trying to create a sample data in json format based on the above avsc for kafka consumer i am getting the below error upon testing

```json
{
    "employeeID": "qtete46524",
    "employeeNumber": {
        "string": "custnumber9813"
    },
    "serialNumbers": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": ["363536623","5846373733"]
    },
    "correlationId": "corr-656532443",
    "timestamp": 1476538955719,
    "employmentscreening": "NO",
    "vouchercodes": [
{
        "voucherName": "skygo",
        "authocode": "A238472ASD"
    }
]
}
```

getting the below error when i got when i ran the dataflow job in gcp

Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"serialnumbers","message":"Array specified for non-repeated field: serialnumbers.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]**

how to create correct sample data based on the above schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [spec](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#complex-types-1)

> The value of a union is encoded in JSON as follows:

> if its type is null, then it is encoded as a JSON null;
> otherwise it is encoded as a JSON object with **one name/value pair whose name is the type’s name** and whose value is the recursively encoded value

So, here's the data it expects.

```json
{
    "employeeID": "qtete46524",
    "employeeNumber": {
        "string": "custnumber9813"
    },
    "serialNumbers": {"array": [
        "serialNumbers3521"
    ]},
    "correlationId": "corr-656532443",
    "timestamp": 1476538955719,
    "employmentscreening": "NO",
    "vouchercodes": {"array": [
       {
        "voucherName": {"string": "skygo"},
        "authocode": {"string": "A238472ASD"}
       }
    ]}
}
```

With this schema

```
{
  "namespace": "de.morris.audit",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "AuditDataChangemorris",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "employeeID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "employeeNumber",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "serialNumbers",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "correlationId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "employmentscreening",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "employmentscreening",
        "symbols": [
          "NO",
          "YES"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vouchercodes",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "name": "Vouchercodes",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "voucherName",
                "type": [
                  "null",
                  "string"
                ],
                "default": null
              },
              {
                "name": "authocode",
                "type": [
                  "null",
                  "string"
                ],
                "default": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's an example of producing and consuming to Kafka

```bash
$ jq -rc < /tmp/data.json | kafka-avro-console-producer --topic foobar --property value.schema="$(jq -rc < /tmp/data.avsc)" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --sync
$ kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic foobar --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 | jq
{
  "employeeID": "qtete46524",
  "employeeNumber": {
    "string": "custnumber9813"
  },
  "serialNumbers": {
    "array": [
      "serialNumbers3521"
    ]
  },
  "correlationId": "corr-656532443",
  "timestamp": 1476538955719,
  "employmentscreening": "NO",
  "vouchercodes": {
    "array": [
      {
        "voucherName": {
          "string": "skygo"
        },
        "authocode": {
          "string": "A238472ASD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
^CProcessed a total of 1 messages
```

Comment: I understood your question, and see the error. `{"string":"serialNumbers3521"}` is an **object**, not an **array**

Comment: i received the avro schema - (1) {"name": "serialNumbers", "type": [ "null", {"type": "array", "items": "string"}]}, seriaNumbers which ever fits the sytax correct it's fine (2) employmentscreening  - right (3) timestamp whichever fits correctly the syntax , can you check and provide a sample json sample data with the above avsc schema ?

Comment: 1) You need to use `[]` for array types. You already did that for `vouchercodes` correctly 3) Convert your time string [into a number](https://www.epochconverter.com/) and dont put quotes around it

Comment: i am not getting trying can you please update ?

Comment: 1) `:`in an array isn't valid JSON. 2) Do you really need union types? You could send serialNumbers as an empty array to denote no elements rather than have the field be nullable. Otherwise, I think you need `"serialNumbers": {"type": "array", "items": ["serialNumbers3521"]}`. And again - remove the quotes from your timestamp value since it's a number, not defined as a string

Comment: Or, you should try the example I already gave in my answer for serialNumbers field

Comment: i tried still same error - Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch type

Comment: What tool are you using? `kafka-avro-console-producer`? Have you tried writing code in something else like Java?

Comment: 1) basically i am validating the json in https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer 2) passing the schema to kafka consumer (instantiating) 3) passing the sample data to kafkka message 4) running the dataflow job 5) checking in big query

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. "Passing sample data to Kafka" - How are you doing this?

Comment: @data2quest Updated with full example

Comment: Fantastic many thanks i have tested the code works well !

Comment: @OneCricketer - when i tried to test with some more data i have encountered this erorr Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"serialnumbers","message":"Array specified for non-repeated field: serialnumbers.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}] "serialNumbers": {
    "array": [
      "556637333","58546373"
    ]

Comment: @data2quest I just tried with `"serialNumbers": {"array": ["serialNumbers3521", "2"]}`, and it worked fine